# Void type not allowed here when using toCharArray?

Tags: java, arrays, string, char, void

This code is meant to compare the characters in two strings and see if they are the same. It does so by taking the strings, converting them to a char array, sorting them, and then comparing them.

```
private boolean sameChars(String firstStr, String secondStr)
{
    return Arrays.equals(Arrays.sort(firstStr.toCharArray()), Arrays.sort(secondStr.toCharArray()));
}
```

When I compile this code, it highlights `(firstStr.toCharArray())` and says `'void' type not allowed here`. What's causing the error and how would I fix it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`Arrays.sort()` doesn't return the array.  You'll need to store the character array strings to local variables, then call sort on each variable, and then finally compare the two arrays using `Arrays.equals()`:

```
char[] firstStrArr = firstStr.toCharArray()
char[] secondStrArr = secondStr.toCharArray()
Arrays.sort(firstStrArr);
Arrays.sort(secondStrArr);
return Arrays.equals(firstStrArr,secondStrArr);
```

Answer (score 1):

Arrays.sort returns void. You can't pass its 'value' to Arrays.equal. it sorts *in place*.

Answer (score 1):

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort%28char[]%29

you should reference two char[] a, b; Array.sort a, Array.sort b and return the Array.equals a,b

```
    private boolean sameChars(String firstStr, String secondStr)
    {
        char[] first = firstStr.toCharArray();
        char[] second = secondStr.toCharArray();
        Arrays.sort(first);
        Arrays.sort(second);
        return Arrays.equals(first, second);
    }
```